# UITableView ScrollToRow function animating weirdly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

The ScrollToRow is not working as I want.
The function I wrote seems to be working fine, but I want it to scroll down to last row only when its added like it happens in chat. When you get a new message, your tableview scrolls to the bottom to read new message.

However, my tableview seems to reload every time before performing scrollToLastRow function (what I mean is every time before scrolling to bottom... it first goes back to top first cell and starts scrolling to bottom from there Every time when a new cell is created).

My code is simple for the scroll:

```
func scrollToLastRow()
{
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.chat.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

To check my code:
here's a link to my repository 
[ChatApplication](https://github.com/FahadSaleem907/Chat-Application)

the ViewController's used for chat is ---> chatVC
the ViewController used to make chat is -> chatCell

I have tried anything I could get all over I could find.
Tried dispatch (without it the scroll function wasn't working at all)

Used the function on many different places (including viewDidAppear)
Used dispatch.asyncAfter for delay.....
but nothing worked.

Comment: are you making `reloadData()`somewhere before calling your scroll function?

Comment: Nopes.. its inside array

Answer (score 1):

@Fahad, you are reloading the tableview before the scrollToLast function is getting called. Please check and please verify at your end.

**Note please update your GitHub repository url in your question properly as it not clickable.**

Use this function for scrolling to the bottom.

```
   func scrollToBottom() {
        let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height - bounds.size.height + contentInset.bottom)
        setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
    }
```

use tableview.scrollToBottom()

Comment: I checked my code multiple times ... I can't understand.. I have made sure to run code both ways trying reloaddata before and after scrollToLast both giving same result.

Plus your scrollToBottom is having same issue (Also I have to put it in If clause to make it work properly)

Answer (score 0):

Use `tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation)` for adding object to end of the tableView.

From the problem you say and looking in to your code, **the animation issues are due to reloading the entire tableView** after a new item is added to dataSource array, 
What you have to do is to use Call `tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation)` with the correct indexPath on your tableView and the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` will be invoked.

Comment: I am not inserting rows separately.... the rows generate according to array count of msgs

Comment: You are writing the scrollToLast() and reloadData() in the didSet of your array.This will get called each time a new item is added to the datasource array, Thus causing animation issues on reloading each time.

Comment: I have tried calling it on viewDidAppear / viewDidLayoutSubview / viewDidLoad... and cellForRowAt also as you can see its commented in many places to show where I've tried it.